# Increase the height of the ask question textarea

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

When asking a question the 200px height is not enough.

This is especially true when dealing with large pieces of code: you have to do a lot of scrolling to see it all.

I'm not necessarily asking for a float out increase; perhaps we could have a nice jQuery expand button that makes it taller, or maybe some sort of user setting.

Also, I don't believe any of these things could have a negative effect, and they really would be useful.

Comment: Use `grippie`..

Comment: `especially true when dealing with large pieces of code`... hmm, maybe we should make it _smaller_

Comment: this has been possible since August of 2008

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my browser (FF) there is a handle below the text area so I can drag it downwards and make it any size I want.

Chrome and all other modern browsers do the same.
[image: Text area]

Comment: It's there in Chrome too.

Comment: Yep, all modern browsers do the same. Touchscreens (ipad, etc) don't, though

Comment: <idiot> (directed at myself)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is part of WMD, not a browser feature (the actual editor input is set to `resize: none`).

Comment: loving how `<idiot> (directed at myself)` got 3 upvotes...